# Flutter: Get User Location and Update on Firebase if user kill the app or terminate

Tags: flutter, background-process, kill-process, google-maps-flutter, userlocation

I have done with fetch location and update on the firebase when the app is in foreground or background but i want if user remove the app from recent then it still update the user location on the firebase

if there is anything please respond it will helpful to me i already use Flutter background fetch package but it doesnt work when app kills

Comment: Hello, did you try Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)?

Comment: yes i used FCM in my app for messaging services but i dont know how i used FCM to get location when app terminated

Comment: Are you using `AndroidAlarmManager` plugin?